# Comma before "and that" in a compound object

Tags: punctuation, commas, conjunctions, objects

> 1. You should have known that he is quite adept at what he does **and that** he has the best conversion rate.
> 2. You should have known that he is quite adept at what he does**, and that** he has the best conversion rate.

Which of the above two sentences is right? I believe it is the first one, as it appears to be a case of compound object and hence should take no comma.

Also, if there can be a case without a compound object and the second sentence has an 'and that' to start off with, what should I do?

Is it similar to 'so' and 'so that'?

Answer (score 2):

The advice of the late Professor Trask http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/joining is:

> Use a joining comma to join two complete sentences with one of the
>   words *and, or, but, yet* or *while*.

Your example contains two complete sentences. One is 'You should have known that he is quite adept at what he does' and the other is '(You should have known that) he has the best conversion rate'. So use a comma before *and* to signal the start of a new clause. The purpose of punctuation is to help the reader understand the grammatical structure of a sentence, and a thoughtfully placed comma will do just that.

Comment: Each of the clauses *that he ...* are used as simple direct objects. Your logic would lead to *You should have known Mary, and John.* Two sentences *could be crafted from that. In general, commas do not separate a simple series of two things, even if those things are clauses. You could argue that the comma is used to create a natural break in the flow of a long sentence and to emphasize where the second clause begins, but not because they are independent clauses.

Comment: There’s a difference. ‘that he has the best conversion rate’ is a clause. ‘And John’ isn’t.

Comment: I thought along similar lines too, but then the fact that 'he has the best conversion rate' is just another object of the sentence created the confusion. That makes it two different views from Bib and Barrie. So what is it now?

Comment: A that-clause (complement clause) is not a sentence. It's a leap to say that Trask sanctions cases where 'you should have known' is merely deducible.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but another one of my English grammar arch-enemies where I oscillated between the two outlined opinions. I finally came to rest at this:

> 14. Don't put a comma between the two nouns, noun phrases, or noun clauses in a compound subject or compound object.
>
> INCORRECT (compound subject): The music teacher from your high school,
> and the football coach from mine are married.
>
> INCORRECT (compound object): Jeff told me that the job was still
> available, and that the manager wanted to interview me.

Sounds reasonable to me what [Purdue Online Writing Lab](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html) says, and this is what I do as a general rule. As pointed out in the comments, there are cases, where it is acceptable or even favorable to insert a comma, so this absolute statement "Incorrect" is ... incorrect.

Comment: [Ross {UCLA} /Hankamer](https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/Kracht/courses/case_046_gapp.htm) consider (50)(b) 'Jack told Harry that Nixon was a fairy, and Alex that Agnew had warts.' acceptable. I'd argue against anyone claiming that the comma was mandatory or INCORRECT. I'd ditch commas I felt unnecessary, but follow the advice 'The purpose of punctuation is to help the reader understand the grammatical structure of a sentence, and a thoughtfully placed comma will do just that.' _Thoughtfully placed._  I'd use a comma in 'Jeff told me that the car park was closed[,] and that the ...

Comment: manager wanted to see me.' if and only if the two disclosures were unconnected. (Ross, incidentally, a distinguished grammarian. Perhaps I'm doing Hankamer a disservice.)

Comment: I was looking for reassurance (for the umpteenth time) in da webz and stumbled across this thread. I felt some counterpoint was needed here; it sounded too much like an unchallenged "a comma is fine" suggestion. That's why my comment. I treat the Purdue rule as a general, but not absolute, rule. Maybe I am wrong, English is not my first language.

Comment: Point taken. I will edit my comment accordingly.

Comment: I am. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Hankamer) is, as usual, spot on: 'Jorge Hankamer is Professor of Linguistics at the University of California, Santa Cruz, where he is also chair of the Philosophy department' Author of the dissertation "Constraints on Deletion in Syntax", ... since published under the title "Deletion in Coordinate Structures".'

Answer (score 0):

14. Don't put a comma between the two nouns, noun phrases, or noun clauses in a compound subject or compound object.
    INCORRECT (compound subject): The music teacher from your high school, and the football coach from mine are married.
    INCORRECT (compound object): Jeff told me that the job was still available, and that the manager wanted to interview me.

This is from Purdue writing to lab. The same principal applies to “so that,” “yet that,” and “but that.” They do not need commas.

Comment: This is exactly what is referenced in Mr. T's answer above.